# onItemClick on AutocompleteTextView not showing text in Android 2.3.6

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, onitemclicklistener

Hi I have implemented AutoCompleteTextView in one of my app where I have to show users options to select from. This works well however just I installed app in my mobile which has Android 2.3.6. It shows the AutoComplete Suggestion when I click on some suggestion, it does not get filled up in AutoCompleteTextView however the cursor shows after some character. It seems that it has invisible characters.

I am using following code to make the AutoCompleteTextView.

```
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter
           (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,state_list);
 at.setAdapter(adapter);
 at.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
              long arg3) {            
           List<String> l = Arrays.<String>asList(state_list);
           ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(l);         
           int selectedPos = al.indexOf((((TextView)arg1).getText()).toString());
           statename = al.get(selectedPos);
```

}
    });

Comment: what you actullay want to say...when you click on selected item..cursor moves ..but text is not visible..then change the colour of your text view make it black..

Comment: Yeah just I tried that and it worked..why is that? cause it works for all other version?

Comment: Theme for text is different for all api levels..thats why you are facing it..